# double.ToString() return wrong value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, double

I have double variable and its value is :

```
double d = 0.000000000000056843418860808015;
```

when i print this variable its print wrong.

```
d.ToString();
```

> Output : "5.6843418860808E-14"

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please explain what's "wrong" with that formatted value?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is "wrong" for him because it is not what OP expected. OP should learn about Scientific notation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to have an output without the exponential notation you need to format your string:

```
d.toString("F25");
```

This will give you the "correct" number with up to 25 fractional digits.

0,0000000000000568434188608

**Edit**: Complete list of formats and conversions are available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) and snapshot for you is below.

```
Original value: 1054.32179

F:                     1054.32 
F0:                    1054 
F1:                    1054.3 
F2:                    1054.32 
F3:                    1054.322
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        double d = 0.000000000000056843418860808015;
        var str = d.ToString("G17");
        var value = str.Split('E')[0];
        var zeros = Int32.Parse(str.Split('E')[1]);
        var outputString = "";
        zeros = Math.Abs(zeros);
        var addstring = "0.";
        for (var i = 0; i < zeros - 1; i++)
        {
            addstring += '0';
        }
        value = value.Remove(1, 1);
        value = addstring + value;
```